# Carousel Page not appearing in Xamarin.Forms template

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to add new Carousel Page in my Xamarin.Forms application but on doing Add new item it's not appearing in the template list.

[image]

I am using Visual Studio 15.9 Preview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Carousel Page not appearing in Xamarin.Forms template

With the release of `Xamarin.Forms` `2.2.0`, we now have the `CarouselView`, a replacement for the `CarouselPage`. `CarouselPage` will be marked as deprecated in a future release. That's why the `CarouselPage` template been removed. You could find it in the `Xamarin.Forms` [release notes](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/63983/xamarin-forms-2-2-0-pre1-released#latest).

Also, you could see the talk Jason Smith gave at Evolve where he specifically says that you should not use `CarouselPage` and you use use `CarouselView` instead: https://youtu.be/RZvdql3Ev0E

> **CarouselView**
>
> CarouselView is intended to fully replace CarouselPage. CarouselPage
>   will be deprecated in a future release. CarouselView is superior in
>   many ways, including its ability to be virtualized and nested within
>   layouts.

As SushiHangover has [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38234911/xamarin-does-the-carousel-page-load-all-the-pages-at-one):

`Xamarin.Forms` `CarouselPage` does not support UI virtualization (recycling).

Initialization performance and memory usage can be a problem depending upon the number of pages/children.

**Benefits of `CarouselView`**:

- Can now be embedded in a page (big bonus)
- Is virtualized

---

## Suggestion 1:

If you want use `CarouselPage` in your project, you need write it on you own:

- [Xamarin.Forms Carousel Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/carousel-page)
- [CarouselPage sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Navigation/CarouselPage/)

## Suggestion 2:

Using `CarouselView` instead:

- [Flip through items with Xamarin.Forms CarouselView](https://blog.xamarin.com/flip-through-items-with-xamarin-forms-carouselview/)
- https://xamarinhelp.com/carousel-view-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write it out yourself. Xamarin Forms can do many things and has made cross-platform development much easier, but you still have to do some of the work yourself!

More info on [CarouselPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.contentpage?view=xamarin-forms).